# Assoc and dissoc on Clojure records

Tags: clojure

Why is there a difference in return types of `assoc` and `dissoc` in Clojure, when their argument is a record? I mean that `assoc`'ing a non-existent key still returns a record, but `dissoc`'ing an existing key returns a map.

But, in a sense, both should produce either a map or a record, but not exhibit different behavior. What is the reason for this dissimilarity?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Record instances are guaranteed to include all the fields declared in the record definition.

When a declared field is removed from an instance, this guarantee would be violated. Hence a map is returned.

Apparently they are not guaranteed to exclude all fields not declared in the record definition, thus new fields can be added to instances.

Answer (score 16):

Record will be converted to an ordinary clojure map only if you'll `dissoc` one of its predefined fields. It's very reasonable behavior, because records can't have undefined fields.

Consider the following code:

```
(defrecord Point [x y])
(def p (Point. 1 2)) ; => Point{:x 1, :y 2}

(assoc p :x 3) ; => Point{:x 3, :y 2}
(dissoc p :x)  ; => {:y 2}

(assoc p :z 3) ; => Point{:x 1, :y 2, :z 3}
(dissoc p :z)  ; => Point{:x 1, :y 2}

(-> p
    (assoc :z 3) ; => Point{:x 1, :y 2, :z 3}
    (dissoc :z)) ; => Point{:x 1, :y 2}
```

As you can see, both `assoc` and `dissoc` return a record as long as it satisfies `Point` definition.

Comment: Plus 1 for including example